# mysql query to count and sum

Tags: php, mysql

i have a table where same data is appearing again and again the table structure is like below.id is autoincrement.pm is for userid.it will appear again and again like beliw table.i want to display the output as the extract of entire table in descending order.    suppose the table consists of 100 rows and the userid 15 comes 10 times which is highest then it should come at the top then the other id which is coming next like that . i tried but not working here is my code as well

```
id    userid
1      33
2      34
3      37
4      33 
5      33
6      37
```

the output i want is

```
     userid   nos
      33       3
      37       2
      34       1
```

please guide . i tried with this code

```
$res = sql_query("select count(userid) as total from tableA");

echo'<table>';
while ($row = sql_fetch_array($res)) {
echo ' <tr><td>'.$row['userid'].'</td></tr></table>';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT userid, COUNT(userid) FROM tableA AS nos GROUP BY userid ORDER BY nos DESC
```

Then you can access:

`$row['userid']` for the user ID

`$row['nos']` for the count

Comment: Forgot the FROM clause when I posted. I have added it.

Comment: hey i am getting error You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'userid, COUNT(userid) FROM tableA AS nos GROUP BY userid' at line 1

Comment: I've tested it in mysql and I get no error, check the table name and fields.

Comment: @Steeve: Are you still having this problem? If you are, verify the field names in your table, as gulyan suggested.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use a GROUP BY statement

```
SELECT userid, COUNT(userid) AS nos FROM tableA
    GROUP BY userid ORDER BY nos DESC;
```

Comment: It would be better to use `ORDER BY nos DESC` rather than `ORDER BY COUNT(userid) DESC`.

Comment: @gulyan hey i am getting error You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'userid, COUNT(userid) FROM tableA AS nos GROUP BY userid' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

Your looping methodology is wrong.

```
$res = sql_query("select userid, count(userid) as total from tableA group by userid order by total desc");
echo'<table>';
while ($row = sql_fetch_array($res)) {
  echo ' <tr><td>'.$row['userid'].'</td><td>'.$row['total'].'</td></tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

Comment: hey i am getting error You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'userid, COUNT(userid) FROM tableA AS nos GROUP BY userid' at line 1

Comment: @Steeve That's because it'll be `COUNT(userid) AS nos` and not `tableA AS nos`

Comment: my query is SELECT userid, COUNT(userid) AS nos FROM tableA GROUP BY userid ORDER BY nos DESC      please tell where is the mistake